# Drupal: how to change taxonomy header on page with items?

Tags: css, drupal, content-management-system, header, taxonomy

I have a menu item like
http://localhost/drupal/?q=category/articles/php

It's supposed to output all stories about PHP,
But in resulting page header (with term name (PHP) ) doesn't look very well.
How can I remove header or change its CSS style?

Comment: Your link is bad.  localhost is a name for *your machine*.  You need to have a live, web-facing server hosting the page for us to be able to see it.

Comment: there's no place like 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for customizing the page is to use the Views Module and activate the taxonomy_term view. Then, you can add to the header field or even create a new template just for that view.

The Drupal Handbook has a lot of great resources for theming and building views:
http://drupal.org/node/352970

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Drupal's theming guide:
http://drupal.org/theme-guide

You'll need to understand theming to edit css or html.